# Entity Framework Datetime Conversion

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-4

I'm trying to get some records from my table (DB: Oracle) by using Entity Framework lambda expression and I have only one date property to filter records (DiscussionDate > DateTime.Now).

However, EF is producing SQL query WHERE condition like this;

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE ("Extent1"."DiscussionDate" > (LOCALTIMESTAMP)
```

Is it possible to produce the script with (SYSDATE) instead of (LOCALTIMESTAMP) in Entity Framework auto generated queries?

Comment: Please don't tag EF and EFCore. Adjust your tags to reflect what you're actually using

Comment: I'm already using EF buddy. What should I tag?

Comment: It depends whether it's EF or EFCore; they're different products